Users running program as administrator
I need my users to be able to run a program as an admin but dont want to get them the admin details.
We work in a remote desktop environment (Azure VDI) and when they run a particular program as themselves, it crashes. However, it they run the program with Admin credentials, even when they log on as a user, the program works.
I want to run the program with admin credentials but without it prompting for them.
I created a ps1 file to open it and when I run it from Powershell run as administrator, it works with no prompts. How do I get the ps1 file to run in admin mode without having to enter the username and password?

I would find out why it crashes.  Does cmdlet have exception handlers (try/catch)?  Most likely you are getting an exception and need to find out the cause.

What is the actual failure? The term crash could mean many things. Is this just a permission denied failure?

It crashes as it cant write to the programs temp folder, 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Filestream Ltd\Filestream 5',  even though I have changed permissions on that folder to allow Everyone access.

This is the reason I'm trying to run it as an admin but without having to enter credentials

ok so it is a permission denied but works if run as an admin account.
